# Menu Disappears On Mobile View

Tags: css, mobile, view, menu

I was asked to take over an old web site and finally managed to get it running again.

Unfortunately, the main navigation disappears on mobile view (when screen size is lower than 800 px width approximately). Link: https://shorturl.at/msARV

I checked the CSS "@media" area up and down, but could not find the culprit. Maybe someone of you has an idea or the solution? Thank you.

Comment: the link you provided takes to shorturl. Where I see no navigation. Are you kidding us?

Comment: I do not know what you are talking about. The link leads directly to the web site I am talking about. Also, I said it already, the menu is NOT shown in mobile view. Did you watch it on a tablet or smartphone or small device? Anyway, please mind your tone! Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You have the following media queries:

```css
// element <ul id="navigation" class="menu">
// (index)line 220
@media screen and (max-width: 800px) {
    #nav ul, #sticky-nav ul {
        display: none;
    }
}

// style.css line 6510 
@media screen and (max-width: 800px) {
    #nav ul, #sticky-nav ul {
        display: none;
    }
}

// -------------------------------------
// element <nav id="nav" class="nab-holder">
// (index) line 216
@media screen and (max-width: 800px) {
    nav#nav, nav#sticky-nav {
        display: none;
    }
}

// style.css line 6509
@media screen and (max-width: 800px) {
    nav#nav, nav#sticky-nav {
        display: none;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you. I saw that, but when I remove it, I do not get the mobile menu, that used to be there. For the sake of having a navigation now on the mobile view, I removed it. It is not the right/clean solution, but better than nothing. :)